# How can I define this 3 way Eloquent Relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following setup. An Event has multiple dates (Instances) on which it runs, and can run at multiple Venues on the same date. The goal is to visit the Event page (example.com/event/1) and have it list all the dates and their venues for that event. So I have the following tables:

events: id, name

instances: id, date, event_id

venues: id, name

However, I can't work out the correct way to relate the three together. I have tried various combinations of `belongsToMany` (using an `instance_venue` pivot table) and `hasManyThrough` but to no avail: I just get one error after another.

What's the best way to go about it?

Here are my Models:

**Event.php**

```
class Event extends Model {

    public function instances()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Instance');
    }

}
```

**Instance.php**

```
class Instance extends Model {

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
    }

}
```

**Venue.php**

```
class Venue extends Model {

    public function instances()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Instance');
    }

}
```

**EcentsController.php**

```
use App\Event;

class EventsController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return 'Index!';
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::with(['instances.venues'])->where('id','=',$id)->get();

        return $event;
    }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 620:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pivottest.event_instance' doesn't exist (SQL: select `instances`.*, `event_instance`.`event_id` as `pivot_event_id`, `event_instance`.`instance_id` as `pivot_instance_id` from `instances` inner join `event_instance` on `instances`.`id` = `event_instance`.`instance_id` where `event_instance`.`event_id` in (1))
```

Comment: Show code + errors you get thats how it works here :)

Comment: Sorry, I was in the process of adding it :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

Event `hasMany` instances

Instance `belongsTo` Event and `belongsToMany` venues

Venue `belongsToMany` instances

Comment: You need to remember, readme is the key, readme is your friend there are plenty examples everything you need (basic stuff like this) is there. If you wish to optimize your tables or whatever take a course so you know how to design well etc.